# Comparing AUC between two subsets of test-fold

Tags: hypothesis-testing, cross-validation, model-evaluation, auc

I suspect that the out-of-sample AUC of my model depends on the number of events in the out-of-sample/testing fold (I am modelling a binary variable, 0/1).

In order to test this hypothesis, I want to perform 10-fold cross validation twice, where I retain X% and Y% of the events in the testing folds, respectively.

Now, my question is - am I "allowed" to compare the two AUCs that I get from this procedure to each other?

Comment: AUC is likely to be biased upward or downward as a function of having a different prevalence of 1 as opposed to 0 on the outcome variable.  You might look up AUC in the context of case-control mix.

Comment: Wouldn't you be comparing 10 AUCs in one condition to 10 in the other?